# MojoFailureException causada por charsetName em Maven Archetype

Tags: java, maven, encode, war

Um projeto de WAR que estou tentando usar de base para executar `mvn archetype:create-from-project` causa a seguinte stack exception após tentar ler um dos arquivos `.java`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create-from-project (default-cli) on project ConfiguradorWAR: charsetName -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:create-from-project (default-cli) on project ConfiguradorWAR: charset
Name
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: charsetName
        at org.apache.maven.archetype.mojos.CreateArchetypeFromProjectMojo.execute(CreateArchetypeFromProjectMojo.java:285)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
```

O encoding padrão do editor e do projeto é **Cp1252**, já tentei com **UTF-8** e **ISO-8859-1**, mudei tanto nas preferências do editor, quanto do projeto e do maven em

```xml
    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <project.resources.sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.resources.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

e

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</defaultEncoding>
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
        <archetypeArtifactId>archetype-wsjpa</archetypeArtifactId>
                        <archetypeGroupId>br.com.example</archetypeGroupId>
                        <archetypeVersion>1.0</archetypeVersion>                              <archetypeFilteredExtentions>java,xml</archetypeFilteredExtentions>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
          <archive>
              <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
             </manifest>
          </archive>
          <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/images</directory>                          <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/portalVAS/images</directory>
             </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

O melhor conselho que tive dos colegas de trabalho, até o momento é de tentar dar replace de todos os acentos do projeto. Tenho um outro projeto EJB com a mesma encode que o archetype funcionou de primeira.

Comment: O ideal seria usar sempre UTF-8. Você tem o trecho de XML que você usa para empacotar o WAR? Qual é o encoding do seu `pom.xml`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa o `pom.xml` é UTF-8, o pack é feito via apache plugin, vou incluir na pergunta.